Can't get PipeWire to work on Alpine Linux
I've recently started using Alpine as my desktop OS, and overall, it's been great! The wiki is helpful, there are plenty of packages, and everything is super fast. However, I'm having trouble with sound.
I followed the wiki instructions to set up PipeWire and configured it correctly on Sway, my window manager. It worked perfectly at first, which was surprising since I’m new to handling audio on Linux and have been using pre-configured desktop environments for a long time.
After a full day of using it normally, the sound suddenly stopped working. I used pactl to check my sinks and set the default sink, but none of them played any sound. I installed pavucontrol to get a better visual understanding and tried every possible option. My output was listed, I could enable it, and the sound bar in from the Firefox source in pavucontrol showed that audio was playing, but I couldn’t hear anything.
I tried reinstalling everything, clearing caches and config files, but the results were always the same. I tested two different outputs—one from an HDMI monitor and one from a

DisplayPort monitor. HDMI Monitor: It usually didn’t work, but twice
it randomly started working. However, the audio played at 2x speed
and was high-pitched.
DisplayPort Monitor: It worked once when I booted the PC, so I went
to test the HDMI one, but when I switched back from testing, the
DisplayPort output that was initially working flawlessly stopped
working with the exact same settings.

I'm at a loss and would appreciate any help. It might just be my lack of experience, but the high-pitched audio and all of that makes me think something is broken. Any advice?
